# Java-script map/array "undefined"

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, html5

Hi when I call the the function below in the chrome console it tells me "Type error cannot read property '2' of undefined" why?.

defining the map:

```
var map = {
FALL:[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3]
    ],
}
```

Function:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(map.FALL[pmx-i]
    [pmy-1]);
    if(map.FALL[pmx-i][pmy-1] > 0){
        return true;
        break;
    }
```

by the way pmx = 1 pmy=3

Comment: This is easy to debug by adding `console.log(pmx-i)` before the failing line, or [using Chrome's debugging tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third iteration of the loop, `pmx-i` is equal to -1, `map.FALL[-1]` is undefined and `undefined[pmy-1]` is an error since you can't access an index of undefined.